# кроссбраузерная верстка (opera, firefox)

Tags: html, css

```css
.man{
 position: absolute;
 bottom: -1837px;
 left: -30px;
}
.manCool img{
 position: absolute;
 right: -10px;
 bottom: -1884px;
 z-index: 1;
}
/*Opera*/
/*@media all and (min-width:0px) {
.man { 
    position: absolute;
 bottom: -1884px;
 left: -10px; 
}

.manCool{
 position: absolute;
 right: -40px;
 bottom: -1884px;
 
}
}*/
@media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:10000),not all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
.man { 
    position: absolute;
 bottom: -1884px;
 left: -10px; 
}

.manCool img{
 position: absolute;
 right: -40px;
 bottom: -10px;
 /*z-index: 1;*/
}
}
/*Chrome и Safari*/
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  .man{
 position: absolute;
 bottom: -1820px;
 left: -30px;
}
.manCool img{
 position: absolute;
 right: 0px;
 bottom: -1820px;
 z-index: 1;
}
  
}

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
   .man{
 position: absolute;
 bottom: -1821px;
 left: -30px;
}
.manCool img{
 position: absolute;
 right: -9px;
 bottom: -1821px;
 z-index: 1;
}
  
}
```

```html
<section>
 <div class="man"><img src="img/manBad.jpg"></div>
  <div class="manCool"><img src="img/manCool.jpg"></div>
</section>
<section id="six">
</section>
```

Ребята, в хроме все на своих местах, а вот в опере и firefox картинки съезжают.как исправить ситуацию? прописывать код в js для браузеров? или можно как-то зафиксировать картинки так что бы не пользоваться кроссбраузерностью как вирант.. подскажите!

Comment: И при изменение экрана эти картинки двигаются( тоже плохо, но они в верстке выходят за пределы контейнера. как их зафиксировать на месте?

Comment: Можете предоставить код? (часть с проблемой)?

Comment: Проблема в опере. с firefox разобралась, а вот опера портит все. как только начинаю её править, тут же изменения происходят в хроме. использую вот это @media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:10000),
not all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
.style {background: #F00;} /* только для Opera */
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задайте контейнеру position: relative; а изображению position: absolute; box-sizing: border-box;

Comment: класс!! получилось!! а я мучалась с этими браузерами(